# CActiveForm and virtual attributes

Tags: php, yii

As stated [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/), Yii provides virtual attributes. I added the following to my model:

```
public function getTest()
{
...
}

public function setTest($value)
{
...
}
```

In my CActiveForm I use the following for a Textfield:

```
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'test'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->textField($model,'test'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'test'); ?>
</div>
```

When opening the form, the get-Method is called (verified with the debugger). Saving the record does not call the setter (every other attribute is saved normally and working).

Anyone there to help me out on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing to define a rule for the variable "test".

```
public function rules()
{
     $rules[] = array('test','safe');
     return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well before and the result was "Eigenschaft CSafeValidator.0 ist nicht definiert.", in English: "Property CSafeValidator.0 is undefined.". No idea where to change this as I'm quite new to Yii.

Comment: Found my problem, rules() was indeed not defined correctly. I ommitted the 'safe' option, which lead to my problem. So your answer is 100% correct.